# How to clear modal values after submitting

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am new to Meteor and Javascript.  I have slowly figured out how to set up a modal form that will show up when I click a button, and can capture my form data and have the form close when I click submit.  Where I am stuck is that whenever I click the button to add more data, the previous values are still in the modal form.  I have tried most of the other answer and examples I have found, but I can't seem to figure out what I need to do to make it clear the values.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Here is what I have currently:

Modal Template

```
<template name="addButton">
  <div class="modal fade" id="addButton">
  <form>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add Button</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="buttonOrder">Button Order</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="buttonOrder">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="buttonName">Button Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="buttonName">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="buttonDescription">Button Description</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="buttonDescription">
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </form>
  </div>
</template>
```

Modal JS Helper

```
Template.addButton.events({
    'submit form': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var button = {
            buttonOrder: $(e.target).find('[name=buttonOrder]').val(),
            buttonName: $(e.target).find('[name=buttonName]').val(),
            buttonDescription: $(e.target).find('[name=buttonDescription]').val()
        }
        button._id = Buttons.insert(button);

        $('#addButton').modal('hide');
        $(this).removeData('#addButton.modal');
    }
})
```

@Jeremy-s

I couldn't get your suggestion to work, although the Session key suggestion got me a solution that did for work with Bootstrap 2 but not with Bootstrap 3.  I did finally get things working with Bootstrap 3, although I doubt it is the most elegant solution.  I added ids to the elements and just set the value for each element to null like so:

```
$('#addButton').modal('hide')  
$('#buttonOrder').val(null);  
$('#buttonName').val(null);  
$('#buttonDescription').val(null);
```

Now I just need to figure out why I can't get it to work with the Session key and Bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to go is to use [Meteor's findAll](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_findAll) to find the inputs in the template, then iterate through them and set the value of each input to null. The findAll is a jquery selector but is limited here to the context of the template.

```
Template.addButton.events({
  'submit form': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var button = {
      buttonOrder: $(e.target).find('[name=buttonOrder]').val(),
      buttonName: $(e.target).find('[name=buttonName]').val(),
      buttonDescription: $(e.target).find('[name=buttonDescription]').val()
    }

    button._id = Buttons.insert(button);

    _.each(
      this.findAll("input"),
      function(element){element.value = null}
    );

    $('#addButton').modal('hide');
  }
})
```

Note also that instead of using jquery to show and hide the modal, Meteor's preferred approach would be to add and remove it completely from the DOM based on a reactive source like a Session key. I would look at Meteor's [reactivity summary](http://docs.meteor.com/#reactivity) for additional guidance on how to do this.